# How to change the installaion of 19c binaries

Tags: oracle19c

I have installed 19c software as non-Container database and
also created the regular 19c database using the below response file parameter

oracle.install.db.ConfigureAsContainerDB=false

My question is it possible to create a Container database using the same installed binaries ?.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Just choose/enable the container option instead of non-CDB.

Comment: Ho do I enable it.  Please note that I have already completed the installation and created the non-container DB. I guess I  can not change the option in the DB.   Then how can I change the Installation parameter to  oracle.install.db.ConfigureAsContainerDB=TRUE.  Can I do run the runInstaller once again and  I have to re-create the database ?.

Comment: Use the Database Creation Assistant (dbca) to create another instance and choose the container configuration for the instance. You can have multiple database instances on the same server, all using the same binaries. You can also use dbca to create a new response file.